# Sub select fails with "Duplicate column name 'NULL'"

Tags: mysql

I've extracted the following "complete minimal example" from my actual query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 1, null, null ) AS tmp LIMIT 1
```

Expected result:

```
| 1 | NULL | NULL |
```

Actual result:

> 1060 - Duplicate column name 'NULL'

What am I doing wrong? Do I really have to convert my query into the following *very* cumbersome variation:

```
SELECT tmp.a, tmp.b, tmp.c FROM ( SELECT 1 a, null b, null c ) AS tmp LIMIT 1
```

If yes, why so? Normally, MySQL doesn't try to hurt me :o

Comment: Downvoter please elaborate, thank you - I'm happy to improve my question.

Comment: Like the error message says, you can't have duplicate column names. What do you want to call the columns? You can do something like `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 1, null AS n1, null AS n2 ) AS tmp LIMIT 1`

Comment: @JJJ Post this as an answer if you are correct.

Comment: @JJJ: I don't want to name the columns at all. I simply want to select them  for a `INSERT INTO () SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is MySQL throwing the error? Becase column names must be unique within a table.

In the example query, `tmp` is a derived table, consisting of three columns.

If you assign an *alias* to an expression in the SELECT list, MySQL will use the alias as the column name. Without an alias, MySQL will derive a column name to assign.

Your query is essentially shorthand for:

```
  SELECT tmp.*
    FROM ( SELECT 1     AS `1` 
                , null  AS `NULL`
                , null  AS `NULL`
         ) tmp
   LIMIT 1
```

---

As a workaround, just assign a unique alias to either the 2nd or 3rd columns.

Comment: Unfortunate, that it doesn't just number them from 1 to n, but okay, I guess that's what you have to do...

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify at least one column alias:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS n, null AS col1, null AS col2) AS tmp LIMIT 1
```